# How do I avoid invalid-index errors when removing user-selected items from a TreeView in a loop?

Tags: delphi, listview, treeview, vcl

I have a treeview and a listview, and a button that should move selected items from the treeview to the listview. The selection and the transfer are happening perfectly fine, but deleting the items from the treeview is not. It only works if I select a single item under the treeview. When I have `TreeView1.MultiSelect := True`, then there is a problem.

Here is the code I am using:

```
For i := 0 to TreeView1.Items.Count-1 do Begin
 If TreeView1.Items[i].Selected then
 Begin
 Itm := ListView1.Items.add;
 .....
 TreeView1.Items[i].Delete
```

The above code gives an invalid index after certain selection. Not perfect sometimes only one out of two selected are added.

**Tried:**

1. `For i := TreeView1.Items.Count to 1 do Begin`
2. Populated listview first and then tried to delete from treeview, instead of simulatainously doing it. Same error.
3. Tried to store Parent and Child in an array and then later delete them with the name. Problem is particular item not selected in treeview.

This is the code which is not working when I select the last element all of the elements in the parent node get copied

```
for Itr := TreeView1.Items.Count-1 downto 0 do Begin
  if TreeView1.Items[Itr].Selected then
  begin
    Str := TreeView1.Items[Itr].Parent.Text + ' ,' + TreeView1.Items[Itr].Text;
    TrimLeft(Str);
    for k := 0 to SaveList.Count -1 do Begin
      If ansipos(Str, SaveList[k]) > 0 Then Begin
        Value := StringReplace(SaveList[k], Str, '',[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
      End;
    End;
    Itm := ListView1.Items.Add;
    Itm.Caption := TreeView1.Items[Itr].Parent.Text;
    Itm.SubItems.Add(TreeView1.Items[Itr].Text);
    Itm.SubItems.Add(Value);
    TreeView1.Items[Itr].Delete
  end;
End;
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your for loop as:

```
For i := TreeView1.Items.Count-1 downto 0 do 
....
```

---

Edit after new code presented

You did not show the actual error message, nor on which line it happens, but I assume it is on  this line

```
Str := TreeView1.Items[Itr].Parent.Text + ' ,' + TreeView1.Items[Itr].Text;
```

for a TreeView item at the root level. Those don't have a parent (IOW `Item[itr].Parent` is `nil`) and the result is an `Access violation` error. You need to check that the item has a parent before attempting to access the parent.

If your error is something else, please clarify.

---

Edit, added workaround

As @MBo reported, the reason is that the selection changes during deletion. To prevent this, you can use the following workaround.

Declare a boolean field, say, `TreeView1_Deleting` in your form and an `OnChanging` event for the tree view.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TreeView1: TTreeView;
    Button1: TButton;
    ...
    procedure TreeView1Changing(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode;
      var AllowChange: Boolean);
  private
    TreeView1_Deleting: boolean;
  end;
```

and the implementation of the `OnChanging`event:

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1Changing(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode;
  var AllowChange: Boolean);
begin
  if TreeView1_Deleting then
    AllowChange := False;
end;
```

Finally, in the procedure where you delete the selected nodes

```
begin
  TreeView1_Deleting := True; // Add this line

  for i := TreeView1.Items.Count-1 downto 0 do
  begin
    if TreeView1.Items[i].Selected then
    begin
      // copy values to listview
      // and finally delete the node
      TreeView1.Items[i].Delete;
    end;
  end

  TreeView1_Deleting := False; // Add this line
end;
```

Remember what I said earlier regarding accessing the `Parent` property of a root level node.

Comment: I am sorry, Its Downto 0 only, small typo

Comment: @siddharthtaunk Note also `TreeView1.Items.Count-1` !

Comment: I am Getting invalid index error as soon as I select the last Item in the tree. And more than two or three Items in the tree and @Tom Noted

Comment: @siddharthtaunk Please then, show the actual code (copy - paste) in your question. Looping down from `count-1` to 0 can not give an invalid index.

Comment: @siddharthtaunk If I have answered your question, [please read](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and if it solved your problem, please consider accepting my answer. [Read more](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: There is one more question which I would like to ask. The inner for loop which u see in my code is to extract the value from the tstringlist. The bug is fixed now and working fine. How do I do the reverse. What I am doing is this..... directly tlistview. Items (i). Caption. Text extract data from the list. .... and then I am local node variable. And then treeview. Addchild ('items caption'. ' items. Substring') but this does not work as intended. Why?

Comment: @siddharthtaunk You are welcome with more questions, just enter a **new one**. SO likes focused, single topic questions and I or  somebody else will be gald to help you. I believe your new question is not related to invalid indexes. So, just post a new question and include sufficient code (including variable declarations). Also, some sample data before and after your processing, would help to understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that this code really clears the whole branch or all the tree (if the last element is chosen) (XE3, Win7/32):

```
  for I := TreeView1.Items.Count - 1 downto 0 do begin 
    if TreeView1.Items[i].Selected then begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(TreeView1.Items[i].Text);
      TreeView1.Items[i].Delete;
    end;
  end;
```

And it outputs both selected node label and parent labels up to root level - so **selection jumps level up during deletion** (I don't see a reason in treeview sources)

Workaround: mark selected nodes, remove selection, delete marked:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  for I := TreeView1.SelectionCount - 1 downto 0 do begin
      Node := TreeView1.Selections[i];
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Node.Text);
      Node.Data := Pointer(-1);
  end;
  TreeView1.Selected := nil;
  for I := TreeView1.Items.Count - 1 downto 0 do
     if TreeView1.Items[i].Data = Pointer(-1) then
        TreeView1.Items[i].Delete;
```

Comment: What a nasty thing! This must be  bug. Have you possibly reported it?

Comment: @Tom Brunberg I doubt - is it Delphi or Windows control behavior

Comment: Yes, that's the question. Like you, I found no reason yet (after just tracing ones through the deletion) in Delphi code.

Comment: I'd prefer to have local array or list of nodes instead. Who knows what he could keep in the .Data - it is not warranted to be available for a mark. And it is not warranted to never already contain -1 for some reason, even the memory garbage

Comment: `I don't see a reason in treeview sources` - why should they be there? I think the selected list is an array of integer hid deep within Windows GDI - and as long as you delete the trees themselves - the "selected numbers" array Is a separate entity that retains its value.

Comment: Yes there is a bug in the above code but have found the workaround taking help for this post and from @tom post. They were really helpful. Instead of a pointer we assigned the node text to 0 and 1 and then checked each node for this condition instead of checking selection. That worked