# Data not being populated in TreeView from ListView

Tags: delphi, treeview

I want the selected List Data to populate the tree

Here was my attempt towards it

```
if ListView1.Items[Count].Selected then
begin
  Root := ListView1.Items[Count].Caption;
  for Itr := TreeView1.Items.Count-1 downto 0 do Begin
    if TreeView1.items[itr].Parent.Text = Root then begin
      TreeNode := TreeView1.Items[itr].getFirstChild;
      Treeview1.Items.AddChild(Treenode,ListView1.Items[Count].SubItems[0]);
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

But its creating new node and there is an index error.

Kindly help

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in the first place? What does your ListView looks like? What is your TreeView supposed to look like when the ListView is selected? Which line is raising the index error? Why are you scanning the TreeView the way you are? Using `TreeView1.Items[]` at all is very inefficient in general, but is more so for backwards interation than forwards iteration. Also, if you happen to reach index 0 in the inner loop, `TreeView1.Items[0].Parent` will be nil and your code will crash accessing `Parent.Text`.

Comment: You have asked several questions recently that are related to mishandling of Treeview iterations.  I think you may need to rethink your whole data storage approach so your TreeView handling can be made cleaner.

Comment: [Yesterday you said the transfer was "happening perfectly fine."](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36725780/33732) Use your version-control tool to check where you introduced the regression between then and now. (If you don't use a version-control tool, then you should start doing so today. Delphi has basic features built in that might help for this limited scenario because the regression occurred so recently.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided *any* details about what your ListView data looks like, or what the TreeView is *supposed* to look like in relation to that data.  But I *suspect* your code should probably look more like this instead:

```
if ListView1.Items[Count].Selected then
begin
  Root := ListView1.Items[Count].Caption;
  for Itr := TreeView1.Items.Count-1 downto 0 do begin
    TreeNode := TreeView1.Items[itr];
    if TreeNode.Text = Root then begin
      TreeView1.Items.AddChild(TreeNode, ListView1.Items[Count].SubItems[0]);
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Note that iterating through a TreeView *backwards* is VERY inefficient.  Trees are not inherently indexable, so every time you access a node by index via the `TreeView1.Items[]` property, it has to start with the first node in the tree and iterate *forwards* counting nodes until it reaches the specified index.  You are repeating that same forward scan for every node you access while going backwards.  That is a lot of wasted overhead.